# CE String: Twitterfy Function Creates Bad Hashtag Links

Tags: twitter, ce-string

The twitterfy function in CE String is creating bad links for hashtags (they go to an old URL for an API that's no longer supported). Is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, update system/third_party/ce_str/pi.ce_str.php (around line 1457):

```
$string = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $string);
```

... to this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=%23\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $string);
```